# Device orientation portrait only for one view controller

Tags: ios, iphone

I want only portrait orientation only in one view controller. I am doing this :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIWindow *)window{

    //    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    //    24
    //
    //    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    //    16
    //
    //    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    //    8
    //
    //    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    //    2


    //    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    return 2;
}
```

No success !!
I have tried many permutations and combinations as suggested on [**google**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gKm6VPbKFoiRvATmggE&gws_rd=ssl#q=shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation+portrait+only) but still not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a UIViewController to Portait orientation in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

You should return YES in `shouldAutorotate`, because if your app was in landscape, your view can't rotate back to portrait in other case.

Answer (score 0):

You should try returning YES for shouldAutoRotate to make the below supportedInterfaceOrientations to become effect and also there is no method called -(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIWindow *)window on UIViewController instead use:

This code must go in your view controller which you want to be in portrait only.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm linking you a post where I answered a question like this. I hope it will bel helpful

[How to change only one ViewController to landscape mode with UINavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752223/how-to-change-only-one-viewcontroller-to-landscape-mode-with-uinavigationcontrol/26753002#26753002)